# Applying QStyledItemDelegate to a cell in QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qstyleditemdelegate

I'm developping an application that allows to read and edit json files on pyqt5; the
aplication lets the user make changes to the data, by default it lets the user edit by
hand the fields, however I prefer them to select the information from the a set of options to avoid wrong editions.

To achieve this I am creating an multiple delegates, as an exaple in the code below `Delegate_1` and `delgate_2` that inherit from `QStyledItemDelegate` and rewrites the `createEditor` method. Searching in internet I found three methods from the class `QTreeView` that can be used to apply the delegates to different situations: `setItemDelegateForColumn`, `setItemDelegateForRow` and `setItemDelegate`, the fist two are works for full columns or rows and the third works for the whole tree, however my intention is to use the `delegate_1` for cell with the index `(0, 1)`, and the `delegate_2` for the index `(1, 1)`.

is there a method of QTreeView or a way to achieve that ?

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *

class Delegate_1(QStyledItemDelegate): 
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        combo = QComboBox()
        combo.addItem('BINARY')
        combo.addItem('ASCII')
        return combo

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        txt = editor.currentText()
        model.setData(index, txt)

class Delegate_2(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        combo = QComboBox()
        combo.addItem('True')
        combo.addItem('False')
        return combo

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        txt = editor.currentText()
        model.setData(index, txt)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QStandardItemModel(2, 2)
    
    it = QStandardItem('File_mode')
    model.setItem(0, 0, it)
    it = QStandardItem('ASCII') # apply delegate_1 to the cell
    model.setItem(0, 1, it)

    it = QStandardItem('Opened')
    model.setItem(1, 0, it)
    it = QStandardItem('True') # apply delegate_2 to the cell
    model.setItem(1, 1, it)

    t = QTreeView() # <- it's json data 
    t.setModel(model)
    t.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, Delegate_1()) # <- column 1  
    #t.setItemDelegate(Delegate()) # <- all cells
    t.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the createEditor method, you can call the index.row() and index.column() methods, and depending on the row and column values, create the necessary editor.

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    if index.row() == 0 and index.column() == 1:
        combo = QComboBox()
        combo.addItem('BINARY')
        combo.addItem('ASCII')
        return combo
    elif index.row() == 1 and index.column() == 1:
        combo = QComboBox()
        combo.addItem('True')
        combo.addItem('False')
        return combo
```

Comment: Note: the editor *must* use the parent in the constructor, otherwise it's shown as an independent window. Also, for index based delegates, it's generally better to also check the parent index if the model is a tree structure.